# How can I know why .NET service is loading too long with Automatic mode?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a windows service, which is developed with C#.
If I configure loading of my service in control panel(on Windows) to Automatic(not Delayed Automatic) mode then after system reboot loading of my service takes a lot of time.
How can I see calls in my service, which is running so long?
Any advice.
Thank you!

Comment: A very basic way would be to add (configurable) logging to your application. Be able to turn it on or off through the app.config file.

Comment: maybe you Pc is starting other services at the same time so it spend it efforts in doing other stuff? Without knowing anything about your server start method no one here can say more

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in Visual Studio Profiler (available now in the VS.net 2013 Community Edition, but previously restricted to paid-for versions of Visual Studio). Start your Windows Service module from within VS.net and profile the calls it makes. The profile trace will give you your answer. Alternatively use VS.net Intellitrace (usage documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) and examine the trace log.